# How can I have bluetooth enabled at startup?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I have bluetooth keyboards that I want to use on my WinXP and Win7 machines, but I quickly discovered that I have to log in to Windows before I can use any bluetooth devices.

Is there an easy to way set a particular bluetooth device/driver to be enabled at startup rather than after login?

Comment: Are you sure? I can use mu bluetooth mouse in Win 7 64 bit before logging in. I'm using Widcomm 6.5 stack and Broadcom BCM 2045 bluetooth module. No extra settings were needed on my side.

Comment: Yeah, I can use my Bluetooth mouse without having to log in

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I can't use my BT keyboard to log in.  I have to use a USB keyboard to log in, then I can use my BT keyboard.  Am I just using a crummy BT receiver?